# Como fazer alert confirm personalizado?

Tags: javascript, html, css

boa tarde estou em busca de fazer um alert personalizado com o design diferente: por exemplo se o usuário clicar em cancelar abre um alert perguntando "deseja realmente cancelar" só que gostaria dele com um design alguem poderia me ajudar. eu tenho alert mas somente com 1 botão "ok" gostaria de saber como posso fazer para um confirm. Agradeço desde já"[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara da para fazer isso só com CSS de forma simples, se quiser eu faço um exemplo pra vc.

Comment: Me ajudaria muito obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem esta outra versão [aqui](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) também.

```js
swal({
  title: 'Salvar',
  text: "Para salvar clique em Ok!",
  type: 'info',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#28B463',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Salvar',
  confirmButtonText: 'Salvar'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swal(
      'Salvado!',
      'Seu arquivo foi salvo com sucesso.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.22.2/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.22.2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muito interressante, só que eu gostaria de um confirm por exemplo "Deseja excluir?" ai teria dois botões "sim" e "não" só que não sei como fazer

Comment: Editei a resposta, mas, pelo visto vc não entrou na documentação pelo link que lhe passei. Seria bom vc entrar lá e dar uma olhada em cada exemplo e suas funcionalidades.

Comment: Caraca, isso é bem legal, nunca tinha ouvido falar dessa api

Comment: Leandro eu acabei de ver aqui me ajudou muito era exatamente o que precisava obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Como vc falou que uma resposta apenas com CSS poderia te atender, aqui vou deixar uma técnica. O princípio aqui é que o *btn* Fechar na verdade é um `label` *linkado* em um `input:radio` que quando `checkado`faz a `div` que vem abaixo *sumir*.

Veja que eu coloquei um pequeno delay na entrada do modal, mas na `animation` vc pode controlar esse valor se quer que demore mais ou não. Repare tb que quando o *modal* está ativo vc não consegue selecionar nada que está abaixo, nem clicar em nada *(isso pro usuário leigo)*.

*Tentei deixar o modelo o mais simples possível para ficar mais fácil de entender.* Deixei comentários no código.

Veja o exemplo.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#rd {
  display: none;
}
input[id="rd"]:checked + div.bg {
  display: none;
  z-index: -1000;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  /* remover animação se quiser que ele aparece direto sem delay  */
  -webkit-animation: tempo 500ms ease-in 250ms forwards;
          animation: tempo 500ms ease-in 250ms forwards;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box label {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* remover se remover a animação do modal  */
@-webkit-keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes tempo {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- modal -->
<input type="radio" id="rd">
<div class="bg">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="rd">fechar</label>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- conteudo de Exemplo -->
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>100px</td>
    <td>200px</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma biblioteca bem interessante no link abaixo

[aqui](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started)

E um exemplo abaixo:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.22.2/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.22.2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
swal("Parabéns!", "Você Clicou em Algo!", "success");
};

</script>
<head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```